RPI5 RTC wakealarm not waking up the pi
In the past I have enabled the wakealarm like this
$ sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" 
$ sudo sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 3 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"

And then if i do "sudo halt"
it will shut down the pi, and wake it up 3 minutes later.
For some reason this does not work anymore. Was there an update or change or something?
I have the rechargeable battery connected to it, and it is getting constant 5V power anyway.

note, this totally worked in april https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/147758/scheduling-questions-with-pi-5-rtc-and-sys-class-rtc-rtc0-wakealarm/147774?noredirect=1#comment252857_147774

I solved it! Thanks to the folks on the pi github! https://github.com/raspberrypi/bookworm-feedback/issues/277
The reason it works on some of my Pi's before is that i had edited the EEPROM. I erroneously thought these eeprom changes were part of the sd card image.
Instead for EACH PHYSICAL PI
you need to
sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit

and then make these settings
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1
WAKE_ON_GPIO=0

